# Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

first I sorry about path question...

HI

I know that lastest firefox doesn't open in selenium so

I fount `marionette` but `button` doesn't working in `morionette`

so I decide to use old version firefox using `FirefoxBinary`

I want solve this problem reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831062/selenium-not-working-on-opensuse-42-1-the-browser-appears-to-have-exited-before)

In test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

class NewVisitorTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        binary = FirefoxBinary('../../firefox/firefox')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

but...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../firefox/firefox'
```

so i change the code

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('~/Document/firefox/firefox')
```

but it export same error....

test.py -pwd is

```
/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/TDD_test/TDD_Test/superlists/functional_tests/test.py
```

firfox -pwd is

```
/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/firefox/firefox
```

what is the problem in my code???

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute paths instead, and ensure your path spelling:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('~/Documents/firefox/firefox')
```

Comment: thank you about your answer but I trying this solution(I have double check about my path spell , i have mistake about this question page sorry..) but it doesn't working too So I solved my problem using downgrade firfox,, any way thank you Adam!